# deployment of designer workflow from test to production

Tags: workflow, deployment, designer-workflow

I have created a SPD designer workflow in my test environment and want to deploy onto production.
Please let me know the each steps in details as I would be doing 1st time

Comment: I have list workflow and not reusable workflow

Answer (score 7):

Follow the below steps to move workflow into  production environment site,

1. In the Development environment open the SharePoint Designer and export the workflow you want using “Export to Visio”.
2. Rename the vwi files by adding ".zip" extension, now open the zip file and remove the "workflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml" because it contains the details about the associated list, once you remove the file from the zip folder, the association between the workflow and the list will be removed and the workflow can be associted with any other list.
3. After removing the "workflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml" file from the zip folder, then again Rename the zip folder by adding ".vwi" extension.
4. Open SharePoint designer in the production environment and open the site.
5. Now Click on Workflows.
6. Click the “Import from Visio” option from the ribbon and select the altered ".vwi" extension file.
7. System will open the imported Workflow.
8. Click on Save and then Publish

Comment: I can move the wf successfully but all initial form parameters are lost. Is there any way to move them?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to export and import the workflow between environments using SharePoint designer.

Please see the following post for the required steps: [exporting and importing SharePoint designer workflows](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wkng/archive/2012/08/21/exporting-and-importing-sharepoint-designer-2010-list-workflow.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

1. SharePoint Designer 2013 provides the facility to save the workflow as a template, it saves to the Site Assets as `.wsp` file.
2. Then you can export is as `.wsp`, which can be imported to any other site collection goto Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Under Galleries click on Solution gallery, after uploaded `.wsp` file click on `Activate solution` to activate it.
3. Go to Site Settings of that site and click on `Manage Features` now simply activate the workflow to use it in the site.

SharePoint designer 2013, provides the facility to export all the three types of workflows:

1. Site Workflows
2. List Workflows
3. Re-usable workflows.

More information please see the below link:

[Move Sharepoint designer 2010 workflow with a wsp](http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.com/2010/05/move-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflow.html)